# Matlab: Excel COM actxserver read entire sheet

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a large number of measurement data in excel files. I need to read and process this data using matlab. The problem I have is that not all excel files contain the same amount of data.

I have tried the following

```
excel = actxserver('excel.application');
xlswb = excel.Workbook.Open(myFile);
data = xlswb.Sheets.Item(mySheet).get('Range', 'A1', 'L10000').Value;
```

This "works" as there will not be more than 10000 rows and 8 columns (in my case). However, this is very dirty code and I have to check for each file where the data actually ends.

Is there a way to read a whole sheet (similar to the xlsread function)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sheets("SheetName").UsedRange` will get you a collection every used cell in that sheet. However, if cell `L10000` had data and it was cleared, it will still make part of that collection.

Comment: Thanks, this works well!
I was looking for options to identify the last row and column:
    `endRow = xls.Sheets.Item(dataSheet).Columns.End(4).row;
    endCol = xls.Sheets.Item(dataSheet).Columns.End(2).column;`

But this returns a number for the column instead of the letter. I didn't find a way to use the `Cells` object in matlab.

`UsedRange` works good enough in my situation. Thx!

Comment: Happy for you my friend.